# How to implement a case insensitive sort with aggregate in mongodb (3.4)

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to implement a sort in MongoDB. But I'm getting an issue that my sort first includes the capital letters A-Z text & then small letters. I don't want them. 
I want the sort to be independent of the case.
Here is my query,

```
var partnerCollection = [
      from: "courses",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "partnerId",
      as: "courses"
    } },
    {
        $project:
        {
            "_id":1,
            "partnerName":1,
            "phone":1,
            "email":1,
            "courses.courseName": 1,
            "courses.courseType":1,
        }
    },
    {
        $match: findUserDataCondition
    },
    { $sort: { "partnerName" : 1 } },
    { $skip: start },
    { $limit: length }
];
```

If I sort with partnerName, I'm getting result as 
ABC, DEF, EFG , bcd, cde

My expected result is ABC, bcd, cde, DEF, EFG.
Please hekp me in sorting this issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Luckily, since MongoDb `v3.4` the [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-document-fields) option has been introduced to specify language-specific rules for string comparison:

```
db.partnerCollection.aggregate([
  ...
],
{
  collation: {
      locale : "en"
  }
})
```

**Note:** If you also specify `caseFirst = "upper"` parameter, upercase string will be ordered before lowercase.

[image: Collation with caseFirst = "upper"]

Comment: is collation a separate package to use it with aggregate. Currently using beanie as ODM and i cant find an option to perform the collation using beanie.